# How to match an exact word in a json soup?

Tags: python, json, string, match

I am parsing through Patient Metadata scraped from a url, and I am trying to access the `'PatientID'` field. However, there is also an `'OtherPatientIDs'` field, which is grabbed by my search.

I have tried looking into using regular expressions but I am unclear on how to match an EXACT string or how to incorporate it into my code.

So at the moment, I have done:

```py
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

PatientID = "PatientID"

lines = soup.decode('utf8').split("\n")
for line in lines:
    if "PatientID" in line:
        PatientID = line.split(':')[1].split('\"')[1].split('\"')[0]
        print(PatientID)
```

Which successfully finds the values of both the PatientID AND OtherPatientIDs field. How do I specify that I only want the PatientID field?

EDIT:
I was asked to give an example of what I get with response.text, and it's of the form:

```py
{
    "ID" : "shqowihdojcoughwoeh"
    "LastUpdate: "20190507"
    "MainTags" : {
         "OtherPatientIDs" : "0304992098"
         "PatientBirthDate" : "29/04/1803"
         "PatientID" : "92879837"
         "PatientName" : "LASTNAME^FIRSTNAME"
     },
     "Type" : "Patient"
}
```

Comment: Would you mind posting an example of what you get with the response.text?

Comment: Your data looks like json, have you considered trying to parse it as json instead of html? Then you could do things like `json['MainTags']['PatientID']` and get only what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use the `json` library instead?

```
import json
import requests

response = requests.get(url)
data = json.loads(response.text)

print(data['MainTags']['PatientID'])
```